# Unpacking a JSON dump row by row and using its keys as separate columns takes a very long time in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe with JSON data encased in a list. Each row basically contains something like this:

```
[{'id': 'A', 'price': 43}, {'id': 'B', 'price': 57}, {'id': 'C', 'price': 99}]
....
```

What I want is to unpack the JSON object so that the keys go into separate columns in the existing dataframe, and the values are updated in each row under the respective column. Basically the above should yield something like this, with A, B and C as the columns:

```
A, B, C
43, 57, 99
...
```

This is my naive implementation, but it is EXTREMELY slow, and has been running for the last 1 hour on a dataset with millions of rows.

```
for n in range(df.shape[0]):
    for dump in df['jsondump'].iloc[n]:
        df.loc[n, dump['id']] = dump['price']
```

What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: `df['jsondump'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x).T)`?

Comment: No this is not the output that I want. Have shown in the OP.

Comment: df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df['jsondump'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x).T.iloc[1]) Seems to do the trick but it is still very slow